# Checking if box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS code:

```
else if ($('#tos').is(':not(:checked)')){
            alert("Error");
            }
```

And the tos element:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tos" value"1">
```

When I click my submit button, without checking it, the error doesn't pop up. Any reason why?

Comment: There's no `id="tos"` in the element. And you're missing `=` after `value`. Are these typos in the original HTML, or just the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector `$('#tos')` looks for an element with id `tos` which your checkbox does not have. You can either add the `id` attribute to the input element or use the name attribute to find the element

```
else if (!$('input[name="tos-pp"]').is(':checked')){
```

Comment: User2738336, if this answers your questions, mark it as accepted and click on the up arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is not returning anything because the checkbox doesn't have an id of tos. Also, the correct syntax for checking if a checkbox/other input is checked is as follows:

```
else if (!$('input:checkbox').is(':checked')){
    alert("error");
}
```

I composed a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyELV/1/) for your reference. Please see the code, it may help you out.